# How to generate custom random secret key for users when they register in Laravel 8x?

Tags: php, authentication, registration, laravel-8, secret-key

I do not know how i can generate custom secret key for each user when they register. I do not want to use passport, i just want to generate custom .

Here is my code

```
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
//      $validated = $request->validate([
//        'username' => 'required',
//        'phonenumber' => 'required|digits:10|unique:users',
//        'password' => 'required|string',
//        'device_serial_number' => 'required'
//      ]);

      $user = User::create([
        'username' => $request->username,
        'phonenumber' => $request->phonenumber,
        'device_serial_number' => $request->device_serial_number,
        'password' => bcrypt($request->password)
      ]);
      if($user)
      {

  //      $token = $user->createToken('Laravel Password Grant Client')->accessToken;
        $user_secret_key = Str::random(60);
        $user->user_secret_key = hash('sha256', $user_secret_key);
        return response()->json(['token' => $token], 200);

      } else{
        return response('error');
      }
```

Comment: what you want to do with secrect key

Comment: I just want to be stored in database for each user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$user = User::create([
    'username' => $request->username,
    'phonenumber' => $request->phonenumber,
    'device_serial_number' => $request->device_serial_number,
    'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
     'user_secret_key' => Str::random(60);
  ]);
  if($user){
    $token =  $user->user_secret_key;
    return response()->json(['token' => $token], 200);
  } else{
    return response('error');
  }
```

Comment: General error: 1364 Field 'user_secret_key' doesn't have a default value. It show me this error

Comment: make a column in the users table user_secret_key and than ad into the filable property after this try to register user